# Centered Poisson, Scaled Poisson, Transformed Poisson

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Given $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N$ with $y\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

The question is, what is the distribution of $y_i-\bar{y}$ and $\frac{y_i-\bar{y}}{\bar{y}}$, where $\bar{y}=\sum_1^N y_i/N$.

Thanks for your answer.